# How to use GPU for this python file

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

**I have this python file where I am trying to train a GPT2 model from scratch. For the same, I want to use gpu for faster acceleration and I am unable to do so. Help will be much appreciated**

My python code is as follows.

PS : I am running this code on AWS Sagemaker, so I want to use their gpu acceleration.

I have used this  for reference [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/train-gpt-2-in-your-own-language-fc6ad4d60171)

```
import tensorflow as tf
from transformers import GPT2Config, TFGPT2LMHeadModel, GPT2Tokenizer
from pathlib import Path
save_path = 'tokenized_data_clean'
tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained(save_path)
from transformers import WEIGHTS_NAME, CONFIG_NAME
tokenizer.add_special_tokens({
    "eos_token":"</s>",
    "bos_token":"<s>",
    "unk_token":"<unk>",
    "pad_token":"<pad>",
    "mask_token":"<mask>"
})

config = GPT2Config(
    vocab_size = tokenizer.vocab_size,
    bos_token_id = tokenizer.bos_token_id,
    eos_token_id = tokenizer.eos_token_id
)

model = TFGPT2LMHeadModel(config)
paths = ['text_data/clean_data_file.txt']
single_string = ''


for filename in paths:
    with open(filename, "r", encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
        x = f.read()

        single_string+=x+tokenizer.eos_token

string_tokenized = tokenizer.encode(single_string)
examples = []
block_size = 100
BATCH_SIZE = 12
BUFFER_SIZE = 1000
for i in range(0, len(string_tokenized) - block_size + 1, block_size):
  examples.append(string_tokenized[i:i + block_size])
inputs, labels = [], []
for ex in examples:
  inputs.append(ex[:-1])
  labels.append(ex[1:])
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((inputs, labels))
dataset = dataset.shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE).batch(BATCH_SIZE, drop_remainder=True)



# defining our optimizer
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=3e-5, epsilon=1e-08, clipnorm=1.0)
# definining our loss function
loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
# defining our metric which we want to observe
metric = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy('accuracy')
# compiling the model
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=[loss, *[None] * model.config.n_layer], metrics=[metric])


num_epoch = 100
history = model.fit(dataset, epochs=num_epoch)

text = "I think"
# encoding the input text
input_ids = tokenizer.encode(text, return_tensors='tf')
# getting out output
beam_output = model.generate(
  input_ids,
  max_length = 50,
  num_beams = 5,
  temperature = 0.7,
  no_repeat_ngram_size=2,
  num_return_sequences=5
)
print(beam_output)

import os
output_dir = './model_bn_custom_100/'
# creating directory if it is not present
if not os.path.exists(output_dir):
  os.mkdir(output_dir)
model_to_save = model.module if hasattr(model, 'module') else model
output_model_file = os.path.join(output_dir, WEIGHTS_NAME)
output_config_file = os.path.join(output_dir, CONFIG_NAME)
# save model and model configs
model.save_pretrained(output_dir)
model_to_save.config.to_json_file(output_config_file)
# save tokenizer
tokenizer.save_pretrained(output_dir)
```

The code is working fine, I just want it to run faster using gpu acceleration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to activate GPU runtime while hosting the notebook session in AWS SageMaker.
The code will automatically take care of utilizing GPU resources.

Looking at the link which you shared - it doesn't have any custom configs to manually specify GPU resources.

If it's handled automatically by the framework which you're using to train the network, then in an active GPU session it will automatically allocate GPU resources while training.

Comment: okay, it looks like a AWS error, cus the same code is running fine on google colab